# Cannot add to an imageView a gesture detector in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am trying to attach an imageview to gesture detector with the following code. I want in first place with this code to be able to get the color of a bitmap and display a message but it does nothing. What I am missing here? Shall I place something in TouchEvent method?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
    GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{

private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";
private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector; 

// Called when the activity is first created. 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);        

   mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(img.getContext(),this);   
   mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);

}

@Override 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 
    this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    // Be sure to call the superclass implementation
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) { 
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"onDown: " + event.toString()); 
    return true;
}  

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onLongPress: " + event.toString()); 
}   

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
   int x = (int) e.getX();
                    int y = (int) e.getY();
                    Log.d("SingleTapUp",String.valueOf(x+" "+y));

                    int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

                    if (pixel == Color.parseColor("#94e3f9")) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Blue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if (pixel == Color.parseColor("#f0c828")) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Orange", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if (pixel == Color.parseColor("#b3522c")) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Red", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTap: " + event.toString());
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTapEvent: " + event.toString());
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapConfirmed: " + event.toString());
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

We just do this.. for any view `TextVIew`, `ImageView` instead of
`this.setOnTouchListener` we put `ImageView.setOntouchListener`

```
 img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            gDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```